# Angular 1.x ngAnimate in Shadow DOM doesn't register animation times or add enter/leave classes

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, ng-animate

I've been trying to work out solutions for a few hours now - **all the duplicates in SO don't seem to work for me** as they mostly recommend either trying different versions of ng-animate/angular or adding the transition/animation in the relevant classes so that ngAnimate can handle their timings right.

My problem is that all of this was working, and I had all the properties in the correct locations - but now I am migrating our Chrome extension to work under a Shadow DOM encapsulation.

Notes:

- Shadow DOM is probably the culprit, but I'm not sure why or how to fix it. It might also be irrelevant or only play a minor part in the actual problem (it is probably due to bad DOM handling in Shadow DOM + angular)
- I am bootstrapping my app manually later in the lifecycle of the extension injection since it is supposed to only start up after a callback. This might also be the culprit

Here is a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/yvtbBfVHZVRvihAGwr5M?p=preview) - I think I have the case isolated as much as I could here. Clicking the links should open/close the divs after them in a slide down/up animation, respectively. Currently they just open up immediately.

Here are the relevant styles:

```
.view-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 70px;
  bottom: 0;
  background: white;
  transition: all 0.4s 0.2s ease-in-out;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  // slide animation
  &,
  &.ng-hide-remove,
  &.ng-hide-remove-active {
    max-height: 500px;
  }

  &.ng-hide {
    max-height: 0;
  }
}
```

Here is the template:

```
<div ng-show="rchCtrl.view == 'flag'"
  class="view-container">
  <div ng-include="'/templates/extension/article-flag-form.html'"
    ng-if="rchCtrl.view == 'flag'"
    ng-controller="ArticleFlagCtrl as flg"
    class="article-flag"></div>
</div>
```

Bower file:

```
"dependencies": {
    "jquery": "^2.2.1",
    "trackjs": "^2.8.3",
    "angular": "^1.6.0",
    "qtip2": "^2.2.1",
    "ng-qtip2": "1.3.3",
    "angular-ui-router": "^0.2.18",
    "angular-cookies": "^1.6.0",
    "angular-resource": "^1.6.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "angular-animate": "^1.6.0"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "angular": "1.6.6"
  }
```

My angular init section:

```
app = angular.module(APP_NAME, ['template-cache', 'ui.router', 'ngCookies', 'geCommon', 'ngAnimate'])

// ...

angular.bootstrap(shadow.querySelector('#ge-ext'), [ APP_NAME ], { debugInfoEnabled: true })
angular.resumeBootstrap()
```

But after all this, the intermediate classes are never added/removed, and the animation isn't working - hide/show display is immediate.

Comment: Would you like to add jsfiddle or snippet for more help?

Comment: @artgb Here's a plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/yvtbBfVHZVRvihAGwr5M?p=preview which reproduces the problem, hopefully not because I forgot to copy something over from my actual code. Clicking the links should open/close the divs after them in a slide down/up animation, respectively. Currently it immediately shows up

Answer (score 1):

Take a look if this is what you are trying to achieve:

https://plnkr.co/edit/0rmEfPlsn3GsK6rtLalP?p=preview

I did some tweaks on the menu.html and style.css. Basically, what I did was remove things like **ng-hide/ng-show** from the elements that were supposed to have animation and instead I've put **ng-class** to manipulate the visibility while maintaning the animation. The reason that ng-hide/ng-show aren't the best ideas for animation is that they apply **display: block** property to your element, thus any transition applied to them will not work. **visiblity: visible/hidden** is the key if you want to use css transitions.

```css
// New styles
#menu li {
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

#menu li.invisible {
  height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.article-feedback,
.article-flag {
  /* Zero height in normal start */
  height: 0;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.article-feedback.visible,
.article-flag.visible {
  /* When visible, height goes to 100px */
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="menu"
  class="list-unstyled"
  ng-class="{'view-open': rchCtrl.view != null}"
  ng-show="rchCtrl.menuOpen"
  ng-controller="RelatedResearchesCtrl as rchCtrl">
  <li ng-class="{'invisible': rchCtrl.view && rchCtrl.view != 'feedback'}">
    <a fake-click
      ng-click="rchCtrl.openView('feedback')">
      Send feedback &amp; ideas
    </a>
    <span class="icon-close"
      ng-show="rchCtrl.view == 'feedback'"
      ng-click="rchCtrl.openView(null); $event.stopPropagation()">
      &times;
    </span>

    <!-- I've removed the ng-show and added ng-class, so transitions will work -->
    <div class="view-container">
      <div style="background: red;"
        ng-class="{'visible': rchCtrl.view == 'feedback'}"
        class="article-feedback"></div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li ng-class="{'invisible': rchCtrl.view && rchCtrl.view != 'flag'}">
    <a fake-click
      ng-click="rchCtrl.openView('flag')">
      Flag this page
    </a>
    <span class="icon-close"
      ng-show="rchCtrl.view == 'flag'"
      ng-click="rchCtrl.openView(null); $event.stopPropagation()">
      &times;
    </span>
    <div class="view-container">

      <!-- I've removed the ng-show and added ng-class, so transitions will work -->
      <div style="background: blue;"
        ng-class="{'visible': rchCtrl.view == 'flag'}"
        class="article-flag"></div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Let me know if there's any other questions about my plnkr.

Comment: Hmm, I'm aware of that method, I was just hoping to fix the actual problem, if I can. This is probably what I'll go with as time for the task runs out. Thanks! I'll wait to see if anyone else has any ideas before accepting/rewarding

Comment: The actual problem here, however, is that classes `ng-hide-active` and `ng-hide-active-remove` are never applied.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing this from the css part:

```
.ng-hide:not(.ng-hide-animate) {
  /* These are just alternative ways of hiding an element */
  display: block!important;
  position: absolute;
  top: -9999px;
  left: -9999px;
}
```

as mentioned [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide#overriding-ng-hide-) and in [Bruno Poeta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8514851/bruno-poeta) answer.